# How to avoid Gutenberg crash after code upload?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a question about Gutenberg Blocks: due to the Blocks structure, every time I update the render of my block, either on back- or front-end, the block crashes, because the data saved to the db are different from those of the updated block. **Is there a workaround to this problem?** Because if I use my block multiple times in my editor and in several posts as I plan to do, at the first update I should manually update all my posts and of course this would be nonsense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have already authored a block and are releasing a new version, its advisable to deprecate the older block version. If the old block content can be transitioned into the updated rendered content, provide a `migrate` function and/optionally a `isEligible` function to handle the transformation (see [Block Deprecation in the Block Editor Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-deprecation/) for examples). If you follow this path, you won't have to update all your posts that use your block - the update will be handled gracefully.

Alternatively, if you are doing active development/testing of a unreleased block where the output in edit() changes frequently, you could temporarily disable the save() function via:

```
save(){ return  null }
```

Once you have finalized content the edit() function renders, remember to update the save() function to match so no [validation errors](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/#validation-faq) occur.

Also worth noting, if your blocks purpose is only [saving meta values](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/metabox/meta-block-1-intro/) to the database then the save function should also return null.